# Removing Formatting from Text Box Controls - InfoPath

Tags: textbox, formatting, infopath2010, strikethrough, infopath-forms-services

I'm working in InfoPath and somehow created about 16 Text Box Controls with formatting that I cannot override in terms of text size as well as strikethroughs.  Any suggestions to be able to remove the formatting and be able to maintain these controls?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you got into the code and accessed the toolbar.  If you right click on the textbox and go to properties it should take you to the properties window.  Make sure under the space next to "Text" in the properties window is blank.

Comment: Disregard the "Text" bit.